# Shorewall filling up my log files on Debian, how do I stop it?

Tags: debian, firewall

I am running Shorewall as a firewall and NAT on a Debian 6.0.

I have a problem now with my /var/log/syslog and /var/log/messages getting filled with hundreds of thousands of lines like this:

```
Aug 15 22:37:34 pathfinder kernel: [ 3091.789049] Shorewall:loc2fw:REJECT:IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:32:4d:7a:d7:53:00:24:8c:df:44:48:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.100 DST=83.233.146.100 LEN=104 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=29973 PROTO=UDP SPT=60003 DPT=53247 LEN=84 
Aug 15 22:37:37 pathfinder kernel: [ 3094.790387] Shorewall:loc2fw:REJECT:IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:32:4d:7a:d7:53:00:24:8c:df:44:48:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.100 DST=83.233.146.100 LEN=104 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=29974 PROTO=UDP SPT=60003 DPT=53247 LEN=84
```

I am not sure why the 192.168.1.100 machine is doing this (trying to reach my public IP from within the internal networkinterface eth0 on the router. It doesn't matter much right now, but I want to stop getting my logs filled with this.

My log settings look like this /etc/shorewall/shorewall.conf

```
###############################################################################
#                              L O G G I N G
###############################################################################

LOGFILE=/var/log/messages

STARTUP_LOG=/var/log/shorewall-init.log

LOG_VERBOSITY=1

LOGFORMAT="Shorewall:%s:%s:"

LOGTAGONLY=No

LOGRATE=

LOGBURST=

LOGALLNEW=

BLACKLIST_LOGLEVEL=

MACLIST_LOG_LEVEL=info

TCP_FLAGS_LOG_LEVEL=""
# above was in original setting info

SMURF_LOG_LEVEL=info

LOG_MARTIANS=Yes
```

I have tried setting the log_verbosity to both 0 and -1 without any success. I have also tried (as you can see) to change the tcp_flag_log_level to empty string.

What part of shorewall produces these messages, and how can I stop them from appearing in my log file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the issue!

The /etc/shorewall/policy looked like this

```
###############################################################################
#SOURCE         DEST            POLICY          LOG LEVEL       LIMIT:BURST

loc             net             ACCEPT
loc             $FW             ACCEPT
net             all             DROP            info
$FW             net             ACCEPT
# THE FOLLOWING POLICY MUST BE LAST
all             all             REJECT          info
```

I changed this to

```
###############################################################################
#SOURCE         DEST            POLICY          LOG LEVEL       LIMIT:BURST

loc             net             ACCEPT
loc             $FW             ACCEPT
net             all             DROP            warn
$FW             net             ACCEPT
# THE FOLLOWING POLICY MUST BE LAST
all             all             REJECT          info
```

and finally my log files are sane again.

Answer (score 0):

In /etc/cron.d i've placed a file: log2zero.
Basically it runs ecery 8 minutes a command to set logfiles greater than 100mb to zero.

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
*/8 * * * *   root  find /var/log /var/local/log -size +100M -type f | while read file; do cat /dev/null > $file && echo "$file > 100M (set to zero)"; done
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, but I would prefer to avoid the output in the first place. If I delete them then I will be unable to check them for other things in the future.